# Intuitively understanding the formulation of Utility as 1 - alpha of a reward

Tags: self-study, loss-functions, decision-theory

I was reading the construction of a utility function in "Statistical Decision Theory and Bayesian Analysis" by Jim Berger (page 52) -- below.

[image]

So I get that if say you have two outcomes -- one the worst possible with reward r0 = 0 and one that best possible with reward r2 = 1 and if you are trying to determine the utility of reward r3, you can propose a gamble where the utility of r3 is equivalent to a gamble r1 with odds alpha and r2 with odds (1 - alpha) -- I follow it up to this part.

What I don't understand intuitively is why the author then proceeds to define the utility of r3 as equal to (1 - alpha) -- I mean that is the coefficient of r2 -- why not just define it as alpha instead?

Comment: The definition is not the final equality: that's a calculation.  (It requires assuming $U(r_1)=0$ and $U(r_2)=1$, which you only hint at.) The definition is the *first* equality.  What's the problem with that?

Comment: @whuber -- perhaps I misunderstood -- but is it that we just define the utility to be the coefficient of the higher reward -- still confused

Comment: No, the definition quite clearly is in terms of an *expectation* of a risky prospect.  The conclusion that it equals $1-\alpha$ is the calculation, not the definition.  (Am I repeating something I wrote before?)